# Alternate for JLayer in JRE6?

Tags: java, swingx, jlayer

I am creating an application in Java and for some reasons, I have to target the Java 6.

And I really liked the `JLayer` functionality, but unfortunately it was added in Java 7. So, is there any alternate for `JLayer` in Java 6?

Can I use `JLayer` source code in my own application, if it's not dependent on other Java 7 features that are not in Java 6?

Or can I use `JXLayer`? Is it the same as `JLayer` or different in some regards?

If I don't want to include whole `SwingX` project jar for just `JXLayer`, what are the other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JXLayer 3.0](https://java.net/projects/jxlayer/) is what JLayer is based on and I use extensively in our Java 6 based project (which is moving to Java 8, but we'll still use it as its not worth our effort to replace it as it does the jlob we need)

Comment: Ok, but I am not able to find a jar for it. Do I have to clone the subversion repository and build it myself?

Comment: If you're using maven, you should be able to find it there, personally I have the source linked into my code, but that's me. You could also look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxlayer301sourcesjar.htm)

Comment: Well, I would also like to include the code as it's much better. What use you make of `JXLayer` in you project and what kind of project it is? Is it a public project? Just curious o_o

Comment: We use a verient of the Lock Layer to disable component hierarchies mostly. I've implemented a prototype form validation highlighting layer which outlines invalid fields and I'm prototyping a localized error layer to seem a component can't fufill it's requirements due to configuration issues and is disabled, it can show some more information about why the component is disabled